# Flask template com nodejs e webpack

Tags: flask, webpack

Não tenho lá notória experiência com as "novas" tecnologias de front-end. Sempre me dediquei mais ao back.

Pergunta:
Dá para trabalhar com os templates flask (jinja) usando **node** + **webpack** para desenvolver o front? Pois os templates do flask fazem uso dos recursos **jinja** que possibilitam embarcar código python dentro de arquivos html (http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/#the-base-layout).

Atualmente eu tenho usado node+webpack apenas para javascript e css, para html eu tenho feito separado, ou seja, criando templates flask da forma convencional.
Queria desenvolver todo o front no node mas sem ter que abrir mão de usar os templates flask.
Vi que existe um loader para html no webpack, mas não sei como ele vai tratar arquivos html que contenham código python embutido.

Também tenho dúvidas de como funciona esse loader html do webpack, tipo, o que ele gera no final da compilação? Coloca tudo em um arquivo JS? Pois se for isso, então é um problema, pois as views (na arquitetura flask), precisam apontar para um arquivo html, ou seja, ao chamar uma determinada url, o flask retorna o devido arquivo html (informado em tempo de programação), que será renderizado no navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Não, porem você pode desenvolver o backend em formato de uma API json ou graphql, e pelo frontend consumir essa API com o axios, e quando for fazer a integração garantir que o build do frontend separe os assets para a pasta static e as paginas para a pasta templates.

Com isso basta fazer o render_template do índex da pagina na rota que você desejar.

Caso queira um exemplo utilizando flask + vue https://raccoon.ninja/pt/dev-pt/criando-aplicacao-vuejs-usando-flask-como-servidor-web-python-javascript/